# Redux-form check validation when other field changes

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

How to validated field when other field changes and change validation type.

I have two fields

1. selection
2. input text

let's say when I change the selection the validation is fired up and validate the input depend on which selection I chose.

If the selection was 'Name' so it validates Name.lengt.
If the selection was 'age' so it validates number.
If the selection was 'email' so it validates email.

also if the validation is ok and then I change the selection it should fire up an error.

```
<form>
<select multiple>
  <option value="age">Volvo</option>
  <option value="email">Saab</option>
  <option value="name">Opel</option>
</select>
 <input type="text"/>
</form>
```

when I change the select the validation on the input also should be changed.
It's work fine, but when I type a valid value and then change the selection so validation doesn't work

Comment: write a function that takes in the field name and do some simple if-else checking?

Comment: I have some validation and it's work. but when I have a value in the input and I change the selection so the validation doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

How about setting up your component so that each time you select a new option, it resets the validation and clears the input.

```
import React from "react";

class Checker extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: "",
    validated: false,
    currentSelection: null
  };

  //when triggered, will clean up and set the current option to validate
  handleOptionSelected = event => {
    this.setState({
      text: "",
      validated: false,
      currentSelection: event.target.value //the option you picked
    });
  };

  handleOnChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      text: event.target.value
    });
   //write validation logic here
    if (this.state.currentSelection == age) {
      //check logic, setState validated to true
    }
    //repeat for other options
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <select multiple>
            <option onClick={this.handleOptionSelected} value="age">
              Volvo
            </option>
            <option onClick={this.handleOptionSelected} value="email">
              Saab
            </option>
            <option onClick={this.handleOptionSelected} value="name">
              Opel
            </option>
          </select>
          <input
            onChange={this.handleOnChange}
            type="text"
            value={this.state.text}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```